# Site DNS misconfiguration

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, dns, cname

So lets say that  I have a site (wordpress installation)hosted at  `site.hoster.com` and a Domain that I purchased that is `example.com`
How can I redirect the user from example.com to site.hoster.com without changing the URL.
I have a added a CNAME Record but the site's url is changing when i try to enter `example.com`.
 I have tried a bunch of solutions found here on stackoverflow but I can't get it to work.
The site is an apache virtual host.
I have added ServerAlias in configuration of the Apache virtual host but it does not work.
Here is the .htaccess file of the site
`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN ShortPixelWebp
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN ShortPixelWebp` and `END ShortPixelWebp` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

# END ShortPixelWebp
```

PS : I have tried the .htaccess 301 redirect method with varius implementations but it still does not work.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that there is an A record pointing to www CNAME record which point  site.hoster.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Log in to wp-admin, go to Settings → General and change both Address URLs to http://example.com (or https://). Don't forget to clear the browser cache.

Comment: I just did that and after that example.com was redirecting me in an non responsive wp-admin page when normally it should direct me into the main page                                              Forgot to mention that there is an A record pointing to www CNAME record which points to site.hoster.com